# iOS - how to access global signed in User object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, global

User signs-in in my iOS app and gets `token_id` to be able to communicate with a server. App then create a User object with 3 properties: `user_id, user_email, user_token`

As I'm new to iOS I want to ask what is a ***good*** practice to store/access global signed-in User object? I want to be able to get `user_token` and other User's data in any view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use global variable and **extern**, but I think the best way to do it is using a singleton.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just read some articles about singletons in iOS and successfully implemented it.